# Terraform chef provisioner - how to change application version

Tags: chef-infra, terraform

I am wondering if there is any solution that will destroy a AWS instance which was created with Terraform and provisioned with chef in case the version of the application installed with chef changes.

The scenario I have in mind is as follow:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "some_service" {
  //name            = "some_service_aws_launch_config"
  image_id      = "${lookup(var.aws_amis, var.aws_region)}"
  instance_type   = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.some_service.id}"]
  key_name        = "${var.key_name}"
  user_data       = "${file("sh/some_service_user_data.sh")}"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "some_service" {
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.some_service.id}"
  availability_zones   = ["${split(",", var.availability_zones)}"]
  depends_on = ["aws_instance.some_other_resource"]
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 3

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "terraform_asg_some_service"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

The code for `some_service_user_data.sh` is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash -xev



cd /etc/chef/

# Install chef
curl -L https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | bash || error_exit 'could not install chef'



# Create first-boot.json
cat > "/etc/chef/first-boot.json" << EOF
{
    "some_service": {
      "environment": "aws",
      "version": "18.01.123-v02"
    },
    "run_list" :[
    "role[some_service]"
   ]
}
EOF

NODE_NAME=`hostname`

# Create client.rb
cat > "/etc/chef/client.rb" << EOF
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  'https://chef-server/organizations/myorg'
validation_client_name 'myorg-validator'
validation_key '/etc/chef/myorg-validator.pem'
node_name  "${NODE_NAME}"
ssl_verify_mode    :verify_none
EOF

sudo chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json -E 'aws'
service some_service start
```

Now... if i need to change that version from `"18.01.123-v02"` to `"18.01.124-v02"` and run a `terraform apply`, now nothing happens. I would need to see that the autoscaling group is destroyed and a new one is created, creating also the machines and bootstrap them with chef, installing the new version of the application.

Is there anyone that has a solution, please?
Thank you!

Comment: That sounds odd. The launch configuration should see the user data script changing (by the hash of the file) and so require the launch configuration to be replaced too. What happens if you change the `instance_type` and run a plan?

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I change the instance-type, Terraform will destroy the instance, obviously. But what I would like is Terraform to see that the user data changed and to destroy the instance, creating another which will be provisioned by chef and thus installing the new version. It does not happend.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all and looking at the [code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/757055f2a5dfb4ea62207de6c4376088c33e3948/aws/resource_aws_launch_configuration.go#L92) shows that when the user data's SHA1 hash changes then it will force the recreation of the launch configuration as expected. From there I'd expect it to update the ASG in place but not change the actual instance at that point. Is that not what happens for you?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform should automatically handle updating the changed launch config for you, but AWS doesn't actually apply that until you (manually) force new instances to be created by destroying old ones and letting the auto-scaling kick in. This is usually handled outside of Terraform (et al) as the rolling upgrade process doesn't match the convergent/idempotent nature of Terraform. If this is a model you want to use a lot of, maybe check out Spinnaker as it can automate some of this for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As I was saying above, updating the user data does nothing. The solution I've found was to mark the resource as tainted, run a terraform plan and at the next apply, Terraform will destroy the resource and will create another with the new version.

Comment: That is an option, but like I said you would usually update the launch config using Terraform and then write a script or whatever to do the actual rolling upgrade. Doing the upgrade in Terraform makes it much harder to control in terms of how many machines are out of service at once.

Comment: This is just a PoC. We'll be using Docker/Kubernetes and the CI/Cd will be done via Spinnaker.